# Where should libraries go in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Where's the recommended location for libraries in Rails 3? Is it as simple as 'lib'?

I'm not sure because 'lib' seems more like a Rails 2 remnant, especially considering that it's no longer auto-loaded (and there was a lot of discussion about that, apparently).

Initializers are more for (obviously) initialization tasks such as overrides.

Specifically I have a small module for attachment handling (Paperclip doesn't fit here) that's too large and distinct to include in my model, but not generic or worthwhile enough to implement as a gem.

From a functionality standpoint it lives somewhere in the middle among the model, view, and controller. This makes it sound like a helper, but in Rails helpers are intended for views AFAIK.

Should I just put it in 'lib' and autoload it in application.rb? Or maybe I could create a custom form builder to handle the presentation (or both).

I know how to make it work, but I'm hoping to learn something new. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

lib is still the right place to put these kind of things.

Autoloading lib was removed in Rails 3 because of the way engines work, but mainly because it's easy to just add it to the autoload_paths if you do want it automatically loaded and if not, you can require as needed. lib is still in the load path, so you don't need to specify *where* the module or class you're requiring is.

You're correct, helpers are intended for the view, and would not be the place to put any model-related logic.

I'd put the module in lib, and require and include it in your model as needed.

Comment: Very helpful answer, particularly the detail about requiring a module that isn't auto-loaded. Thank you!