# Rails3 custom logging options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What are the "best-practice" custom logging options for Rails3?  Can anyone suggest good gems, or techniques, for logging.

In general, what is the convention for custom, non-controller, non-model stuff? If I make a custom logger like this:

```
#custom_logger.rb
class CustomLogger < Logger
  def format_message(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    "#{msg}\n"
  end
end

logfile = File.open(RAILS_ROOT + '/log/custom.log', 'a')  #create log file
logfile.sync = true  #automatically flushes data to file
CUSTOM_LOGGER = CustomLogger.new(logfile)  #constant accessible anywhere
```

(stolen from [here](http://ianma.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/custom-logging-in-ruby-on-rails/)) Should that go in a file in "/lib"? In "application.rb"? Or in an initializer?

I can't seem to find anything that describes these little differences from previous Rails versions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'lib' still seems to be the proper place to put this stuff.

See:

[Where should libraries go in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794384/where-should-libraries-go-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 2):

This gem works really well for customizing log output:
https://github.com/johmas/itslog

Answer (score 2):

I put mine in application.rb, because it's only a few lines.  I'm lazy like that.  If you put your class in a file in lib/, you'll have to require it manually or set up lib/ autoloading.

Here's my logger code:

application.rb:

```
class DreamLogFormatter < Logger::Formatter
  def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
    "[%s(%d)%5s] %s\n" % [time.to_s(:short), $$, severity, msg2str(msg)]
  end
end
```

....

```
config.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', "#{Rails.env}.log"), 10, 30*1024*1024)
config.logger.formatter = DreamLogFormatter.new
```

Notice I roll the logs every 30MB and keep the last 10 logs.

Comment: Rails uses BufferedLogger.  I read some discussion on the ruby-core mailing list, and it seems pretty arbitrary.  The only benefit they described was non-interleaving for multiple processes writing at the same time, but the Stdlib Logger class for 1.9.2 has a Mutex in it, which appears to accomplish the same thing.  Except Logger is easy to alter, and has automatic log rolling.  I'll just log to Mongo if it ever becomes a major problem.

Comment: Watch out for this -- If you are using multiple processes in production (which you should be), Logger will interleave the messages.