# Rails3 Custom logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I created a new logger

```
my_logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'my_log.log'))
my_logger.info "my message"
```

and I tried logging some bit of texts on this log file.

Here is the logger_level of all my environments.

```
Development = 0 - Logger::DEBUG

Staging = 1 - Logger::INFO

Production = 1 - Logger::INFO
```

This works perfectly in development and staging environments.  But the `my_logger.info "my message"` does nothing in production environment. It doesn't throw any error also. Can you tell what could have gone wrong in just "production" environment with my new logger?

Comment: How do you set the logger level? Maybe the bug is there?

Comment: Maybe file permissions prevent the file from being created? What exactly means "does nothing"?

Comment: the file is getting created. No problems with it. I am using that logger in delayed_job. may be some problem with it.

Comment: set the log level = the severity, not 1 - severity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rails3 custom logging options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937396/rails3-custom-logging-options/6318380#6318380)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to customize the output of the Rails3 logger, try this gem:
https://github.com/johmas/itslog

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in application.rb

```
if defined?(Rails) && (Rails.env == 'development')
  Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end
```